# What is the common context base class used by Java code delegates?

Tags: camunda

What is the common base class used by Java code delegates so that common code can be used to get/set process variables etc?

For a service-task, the process engine context class is `DelegateExecution` and typically, to get a process variable, this context, passed as a parameter is used to access process variables.

```
...
public class CreatePurchaseOrderRequistionDelegate implements JavaDelegate
{
   public void execute( DelegateExecution execution ) throws Exception
   {
      LOGGER.info( getClass().getSimpleName() + ": starting" );

      String purchaseOrderRef = (String) execution.getVariable( "purchaseOrderReference" );
...
```

For a user-task event listener, the context class is `DelegateTask`.

I want to use the same code to get/set process variables so need a base class that has access to setVariable(), etc

I have looked at the Camunda Manual, Javadocs etc but both classes inherit from a number of other classes and it is difficult to trace the inheritance tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be: `org.camunda.bpm.engine.delegate.VariableScope`

So something like:

```
   public static String getVariableS( VariableScope execution, String variableName, String defaultValue ) throws Exception
   {
      Object obj = execution.getVariable( variableName );      
      if( obj == null )
      {
         return defaultValue;
      }
      return (String) obj;
   }
```

Hope this helps!